# Подскажите, как в скрипт вписать верстку и стили?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой вот html-документ, в нем стили и скрипт, который работает с данной версткой. Нужно этот весь документ сделать скриптом, который будет лежать между открывающим и закрывающим тегом script, чтоб его можно было скопипастить абсолютно в любую верстку. Чтоб библиотеки подключались внутри самого скрипта. Подскажите КАК это реализовать?

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.show_popup').click(function() {
  var popup_id = $('#' + $(this).attr("rel"));
  $(popup_id).show();
  $('.overlay_popup').show();
})
$('.overlay_popup').click(function() {
  $('.overlay_popup, .popup').hide();
})
</script>

<style>
  .popup,
  .overlay_popup {
      display: none;
    }

  .overlay_popup {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      z-index: 2;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

  .popup {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 3;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      max-width: 200px;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #fff;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content">
      <button class="show_popup blue_btn" rel="popup1">Click</button>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay_popup"></div>

    <div class="popup" id="popup1">
      <div class="object">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, в html, поменяйте все двойные кавычки, на одинарные. Далее удалите все переходы строк через сервис http://ru.texthandler.com/text-tools/remove-line-breaks/, а после этого возьмите результат и вставьте его в `document.write("code");`, таким образом, вы напечатает в браузере код.

Comment: очень хороший способ, но ВСЕ кавычки менять - можно умереть...

Comment: Это совершено не сложно, в Sublime Text 3, нажимает ctr + f, потом вводите в поле двойные кавычки, и справа нажимаете «find all» после чего вы просто заменяете все двойные кавычки, на одинарные. Думаю это доступно не только в sublime.

Comment: я просто о том, что данный способ действует, но в таком случае это решение немного карявенькое...но....пока самое актуальное, т.к. нужно написать просто один скрипт!!!

Answer (score 1):

Просто вставьте этот код

```
A={//создаём объект с функцией ajax
   XMLHTTPRequest:function(){
      try{
         return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch(e){
         try{
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
         }catch(ee){}
      }
      if(typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined'){
         return new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
   },
   ajax:function(a){
      var b=this.XMLHTTPRequest();
      a.url+=((a.url.indexOf('?')>=0)?'&':'?')+'_='+new Date().getTime();
      b.open("GET",a.url,false);
      b.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      b.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if(b.readyState==4){
            if(b.status===200){
               a.success&&a.success(b.responseText);
            }
         }
      };
      b.send(a.data);
   }
};

!window.jQuery&&A.ajax({//просто делаем запрос, если не подключен jQuery
        url:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
        success:function(code){
            eval(code);     
        }
    });
```

П.С. Если нужен нормальный ajax без jQuery, то обращайтесь... Это- просто сильно урезанная версия.

Comment: Не советовал бы использовать eval, это раз, также отформатируйте код, ибо ничег не понятно.

Comment: почему не использовать eval? Как тогда запустить библиотеку?